# ignoring .vscode

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, gitignore

So i accidently pushed the ".vscode" folder to the github repository. I want it to be deleted from github.

I made a gitignore file and added the name ".vscode" in it so that it won't be tracked and i also tried delteing it using the `git rm .vscode --cached` command and it says `fatal: not removing '.vscode' recursively without -r` Now i do not understand what it says. My question is simply how do i delete the .vscode folder from my github repository. I tried searching on internet but could not find anything.

Comment: Just as the error tells you: you are missing the parameter -r, which is needed for recursively removing a directory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+rm+recursively

Comment: Note that since the commit with vscode directory is already pushed, it will remain on GitHub forever. Nothing short of a history rewrite or repo deletion can remove it.

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove `.vscode` from `.gitignore`
2. Remove `.vscode` from your local repository by running the following command in the terminal while in the repository directory:
   `rm -rf .vscode`
3. Commit this change and push to github
4. Return back `.vscode` to `.gitignore`, commit the change, and push it to github.

Comment: That won't actually delete the already pushed directory from GitHub, as the user has asked.